# middleware that run before any routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to do a token based auth. I'm stuck at running auth before any request happens. For example below code is to get the users, but one middleware should check whether the request has valid token or not.

app.js

```
var user = require('./controllers/user');
app.use('/api', user);
```

user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 

router.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.json(users);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have that logic which is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kCybT9LU), but I don't know where to place it.

Comment: Put your middleware as the second argument of `router.get()` method.

Comment: @GökayGürcan can show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.js register the token authentication middleware with express' app.use() **before** any routes.

This way the token authentication will be executed everytime a route defined after is called. Basically app.use(authentication) is the same as app.use('*', authentication), which means that the middleware is executed for all the domains, not just for '/api'.

auth.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {

        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {          
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });      
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;  
                next();
            }
        });

    } else {

        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({ 
            success: false, 
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });

    }

};
```

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = module.exports = express();

// put the middleware before any routes in app.use()
var authentication = require("./middleware/auth");
app.use(authentication);

var user = require('./controllers/user');
app.use('/api', user);
```

If you want to have the token check only for the '/api' routes, then define the authentication just for that with

```
app.use('/api', authentication, user);
```

app.use() runs the functions given as parameters in given order.

Answer (score 0):

Put your middleware before everything :)

```js
var app = express();

function myCustomMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  if(/**something we need **/) {
    req.haveWhatWeNeed = true;
  }
  
  return next();
}

app
.use(myCustomMiddleware)
.get(/*** everything you want***/)
;
```

Comment: imagine I have to include that in every single routes

Comment: No, you don't, considering how express works, this middleware is called always. Simple put it before any other middleware...

Answer (score 0):

You can define your middleware before defining any routes to make sure they get executed before getting handled by routes.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that before executing the code for route you need a middleware check.

```
    var middlewareFunction = function(req, res, next) {

        // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
        var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

        // decode token
        if (token) {

            // verifies secret and checks exp
            jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {          
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });      
                } else {
                    // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                    req.decoded = decoded;  
                    next();
                }
            });

        } else {

            // if there is no token
            // return an error
            return res.status(403).send({ 
                success: false, 
                message: 'No token provided.'
            });

        }
}
```

Make a middleware function as such and in your route add this function..

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); 

router.get('/user', middlewareFunction, function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.json(users);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I hope this solves your issue.